# Firestore: com.google.cloud.firestore.CollectionReference.where() not working

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to check if a user exists in a nested field, but I keep getting this error.

> No signature of method: com.google.cloud.firestore.CollectionReference.where() is applicable for argument types: (com.google.cloud.firestore.AutoValue_FieldPath, java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [responses.`0`, array-contains, UFZRW7MGV]

```
String[] queryPath = ["responses", Integer.toString(i)]

DocumentSnapshot userPoll = colRef.where(FieldPath.of(queryPath), "array-contains", user).get()
if(userPoll.exists()) 
    return true
}
```

What am  I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you can see from the API docs, a [CollectionReference](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/CollectionReference.html), subclass of [Query](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/Query.html), doesn't have a where() method.  It looks like you want to use [whereArrayContains()](https://googleapis.github.io/google-cloud-java/google-cloud-clients/apidocs/com/google/cloud/firestore/Query.html#whereArrayContains-com.google.cloud.firestore.FieldPath-java.lang.Object-) instead.  Right now, it looks like you're assuming a node.js API instead of the Java API, which would be required for Grails.